How to make SwaggerUI document POST parameters for CommunityToolkit's Datasync framework
I want to build a solution that consists of these parts:

API
Offline enabled Avalonia Client
Admin website

I set up a test implementation of CommunityToolkit.Datasync.Server and inspected the Swagger UI interface. I notice that GET, PUT and DELETE both document and work fine, but POST does not let me type the values Name and Operational of the Ship entity:
public class Ship : LiteDbTableData
{
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public bool Operational { get; set; } = false;

}


I tested the POST method separately via Postman, and see it works fine. It seems Swagger is unable to auto generate the parameters because the Controller implements the TableController class of `CommunityToolkit.Datasync.Server
[Route("tables/[controller]")]
public class ShipController : TableController<Ship>
{
    public ShipController(LiteDatabase db) : base(new LiteDbRepository<Ship>(db, "ships"))
    {
    }
}

I really would like to re-use the API for both the Avalonia Client and the Admin Website. As it stands I can do this, but the Swagger UI does not properly document the POST method.
Is there a way to make the Swagger UI document properly?

Please share Error details.

There are no further details. It seems the TableController makes Swagger unable to output the parameters. If you teste the API via PostMan the POST verb works. I will post an issue on the repo and see what they say.

Solved on version 8.0.2 via issue #118
